# JQuery: first tr with less than X td

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, web, frontend

I'm trying to insert a `<td>` in a table , at the first row which contain less than 3 cells.

something in this style:

```
var table = $...
table.$(some query that brings the first tr with less than 3 td's).append(myTDvar)
```

thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
$table.find('tr').filter(function() {
    return this.children.length < 3;
}).eq(0).append(myTDvar);
```